# Threads and Tkinter not working together

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, keyboard, python-3.6

Trying to practice Tkinter, Pyautogui and threading with a simple (or so I thought) auto clicker.

- It is supposed to open up a menu (check),
- then a choice of buttons (check),
- it opens up another window (check),
- and when you press <kbd>F7</kbd> it starts clicking (not working)

This works fine without Tkinter

Here is code:

```
from tkinter import *
from pyautogui import *
from time import  *
from threading import Thread as th
import keyboard 

root = Tk()
key_loop = 1
k = ""
root.geometry("150x500")
def detect_key_def():
    global k
    while key_loop == 1:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('f7'):
            k = "f7"
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("f8"):
            k = "f8"
        elif keyboard.is_pressed("f9"):
            k = "f9"

detect_key = th(target=detect_key_def)
detect_key.start()
def clicker():
    clicker = Tk()
    root.geometry("300x300")

Label(clicker, text="Start - F7\n\nStop - F8").pack()
Button(clicker, text="Exit", command =clicker.destroy).pack()
if k == "f7":
    click()
    t.sleep(0.01)
elif k == "f8":
    t.sleep(0.01)
clicker.mainloop()

Button(root, text="Auto Clicker", command=clicker).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When I run the code the <kbd>F7</kbd> starter does not work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Pro tip. Do not import `*`. You run the risk of overriding other imports and causing issues with your code. Instead import as something like `import tkinter as tk` to prevent any issues with overriding methods from a library.

Comment: Ok will do. Thanks

Comment: Yea I saw that and fixed the sleep

Comment: I think you need to use `after()` method from Tkinter to manage any timing you need to work with. Threading is an option but might be a little more advanced than you need here.

Comment: @Mike-SMT Actually, while generally not recommended not to use `import *`, it is in this case used by example in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules), which is why it is so popular to do so when using `tkinter`.

Comment: @PaxVobiscum that link is only a use example to show what is possible. It is however bad practice to use `*` in general and should be avoided for maintainability and compatibility. The use of `*` is fine when doing a quick code to test something but should later be corrected to `import as` for cleaner code. Also when running multiple `*` imports you run a greater risk of breaking your code due to overriding common names methods.

Comment: @Matt you wrote `click()` in one of your if statements but do not have a method called `click()`. Can you tell me what this is for? I need to know so I can rewrite this code.

Comment: @Mike that is part of pyautogui
--- pyautogui.click()

Answer (score 0):

Ok so based on what you are trying to do with your code it is probably best to use `after()` here instead of threading. Tkinter monitors all the key presses anyway so you can just bind the `F7` button to the Toplevel window.

The below code will bind `F7` to the clicker toplevel window. When you click in toplevel to give it focus you can use the `F7` to start the auto clicking. I have it set to 1 clicks a second.

```
import tkinter as tk
from pyautogui import click

root = tk.Tk()
key_loop = 1
root.geometry("150x500")

def click_loop(event=None):
    click()
    root.after(100, click_loop)

def clicker():
    clicker = tk.Toplevel(root)
    root.geometry("300x300")
    tk.Label(clicker, text="Start - F7\n\nStop - F8").pack()
    tk.Button(clicker, text="Exit", command =clicker.destroy).pack()
    clicker.bind("<F7>", click_loop)

tk.Button(root, text="Auto Clicker", command=clicker).pack()
root.mainloop()
```